# How can I modify the layer panel of my export of qgis2web in my website?

Tags: layers, editing, geocoding, qgis2web

I export my qgis project with 4 layers and I want put it in my website. 
I don't like the style of qgis2web and I want to edit the code. I putted in my text editor but I understood that is not easy to modify the panel layer.

How do I overwrite it with my code?

Comment: Are you exporting to OpenLayers 3 or to Leaflet?

Comment: I used OpenLayers 3

Answer (score 1):

To modify the appearance of the OpenLayers 3 layers list, open your output folder, and edit `/resources/ol3-layerswitcher.css`. There is an outside chance you might also need to edit `/resources/ol3-layerswitcher.js`, but it's unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to edit your panel layers

https://github.com/davicustodio/Leaflet.StyledLayerControl

Comment: Glad you got it sorted for Leaflet exports . For OpenLayers 3, my answer should help you.